# How do I import or load data from a webhook into Azure

Tags: azure, integration, webhooks

I'm trying to automate sending data from a webhook service into Azure, but I cannot for the life of me find appropriate information. It keeps pulling up how to create a runbook from a webhook, all in azure, but I need to figure out how to pull in the external webhook information into Azure so I can get that running